# Java regular expression to capture text in square bracket which contains a pipe character

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the text in square bracket which contains the pipe character.

For example from:

```
"ERROR|appLogger|[File|name|upload<failed on server:5645>]Execution Failed[check server address][com.package.file.upload]"
```

I want to extract:

```
"File|name|upload<failed on server:5645>"
```

Comment: how much would u pay for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Small correction to catch stuff like `[|]` as well.

Try this:

```
\[(([^\]]*\|[^\]]*))\]
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?31s77).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker had an objection to my solution, but somehow he deleted his comment again - But indeed, there was a problem with edge cases, like matching `[|]`. I updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: @RemyaPoulose try to accept the answer then.?It only takes a second!

Answer (score 1):

this is the Regex

```
(?<=\[).*?\|.*?\|.*?(?=\])
```

Comment: This fails on a string like `"foo [don't capture this] bar [just|capture|that] baz"`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker my bad..thanks to point out..nice thinking there